# SSAS - Count Time Dimension

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, cube, dimensions

I looked at this topic, [Calculating the number of days in a time dimension node - with Grand Total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820202/calculating-the-number-of-days-in-a-time-dimension-node-with-grand-total), but can't seem to get it.

I have a Time Dimension; [Invoice Date].

I want to count the number of Work Days in that dimension for a specified time period. I'm new to MDX.

Here's what I have.

Count(
    Descendants(
        [Invoice Date].CurrentMember,
        [Invoice Date].[Work Date].[Work Date]
    )
)

I'm getting a cube error now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to implement this reliably would be to create a physical measure "Day Count". To do this, create a new measure group on the Date dimension table, and define "Day Count" as the Count. On the dimension usage tab, make sure you set a relationship from this measure group to the Invoice Date cube dimension and not the other dimensions.

Comment: That was a lot easier. Awesome.